# Is there a website which highlights airport locations on a map?

Tags: airport, website

Is there a good website which shows airports (both public and GA)? I can look it on Google and Bing Maps (as shown in the image below). Shown the picture, I have zoomed in a lot to see airport icons (bottom left and top right). I feel that the icon on Bing (right) can be easily spotted than the one on Google (left). Even if I zoom out one level, Bing still shows both airports but Google doesn't.

When I search on Internet, mostly A/F Directories are returned. Wikipedia also has a thorough list but I don't like plotting them on a map to find their proximity.

[image: Google and Bing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FltPlan.com](http://www.fltplan.com) has a great airport mapping engine.  Just click on "Nearby Airports" on the main page and enter the location that you want to search around.

You can search by zip code, city name, or an existing airport id and filter the results by minimum runway length, distance, approach types, and fuel.

Here's an example of the results:

[image: Nearby Airports 1]
[image: Nearby Airports 2]

Answer (score 5):

[SkyVector](http://skyvector.com) is a great resource for aviation maps and data of all kinds. It offers worldwide sectional- and low-ifr-type charts, and a fully-featured [Airports section](http://skyvector.com/airports).

I'm not sure if you also want airport diagrams, but you may also get some decent results with [OpenStreetMap](http://openstreetmap.org). The open source maps have some hit-or-miss levels of detail for airports, some including full taxiway and runway data. Others are just property outlines.

Comment: SkyVector is great but it is hard to find airports, unless there is some highlight I can turn on. OpenStreetMap is slow but did provide the information you mentioned.

Comment: Ah, yeah, I see what you mean. Aside from using aviation charts, I'm not sure there are very good options highlighting airports. SkyVector's METAR mode helps, but it's obviously only gonna catch airports with weather reporting.

Answer (score 3):

[World Aero Data](http://worldaerodata.com/) shows airports on a map, although I did find an [airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bay_Bridge_Airport) which isn't mentioned.

Other than that, the map and airports are easily visible, irrespective of zoom level.

Answer (score 2):

[OurAirports](http://ourairports.com), the continuation of DAFIF by community effort (since Australia (and possibly some other countries) copyrighted their official data) would be the obvious one.

Answer (score 0):

For the purposes you state, I think that [VFRMap](http://vfrmap.com/) is the best resource.

I really like [SkyVector](http://skyvector.com/) for aeronautical planning purposes, but the distinction of VFRMap is the inclusion of some of the various Google Map options in addition to the aeronautical charts. This offers what is essentially Google Maps with airport locations overlaid.

See the following two examples from VFRMap depicting first the Sectional background and then the Google Map Roadmap background.

[image]

[image]

Additional map backgrounds include VFR and IFR aeronautical charts, as well as Google's Roadmap, Satellite, and Terrain maps.

One of VFRMap's shortcomings is that it's airport database is limited to the United States.